# How to update Cordova in an existing Phonegap app?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, android-studio

Google have informed me that some of our Phonegap apps are using a version of Cordova that is now considered insecure, and needs to be updated but it's been so long since I  built these apps now that the documentation isn't making much sense to me!

I use Android Studio on GNU/Linux and as far as I can tell, I used NodeJS (the npm commandline) to create a basic Phonegap app, and then imported this into Android Studio. A lot of the documentation references phonegap or cordova commandlines which simply don't exist for me - I only have npm installed.

I ran, from a commandline, "npm update -g cordova" which appears to have brought Cordova v4 in successfully but how do I update the individual apps to use this? In platforms/android/libs within each project I have a cordova-3.0.0.jar file and in platforms/android I have a cordova folder... Do I just replace this folder and the .jar file and use the refactor functions of Android Studio? Where would I copy these from? Presumably the update npm performed has dumped the newer files somewhere...

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading an existing app to the latest version of Cordova is usually a straightforward process:

```
 cd path/to/my-app
 cordova platform update android
```

Comment: Hmm... I didn't have the Phonegap commandline installed. I've now installed with "npm install -g phonegap", CD'd to the project and tried your line above but I'm getting "Error: project directory could not be found" ? I've tried from both the project root and from platforms/android

Comment: Is this a Cordova project or a PhoneGap project? You can tell by the presence of a `cordova` folder in your project directory

Comment: I have a Cordova folder but it's a Phonegap project. I used to use Eclipse if that's any help? These were imported into Android Studio later on. Additionally if I try "cordova platform update android" I get "Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project."

Comment: ...Actually, it's supposed to be a Phonegap project but looking at the config files everything suggests Cordova. Also, Android Studio is always telling me that I should upgrade it to the Gradle build system but I've never seen the need to and I've no idea what that is =). I'm getting more and more confused by the hour here!